# Reverse for 'tagged' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['^tag/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$']

Tags: django, django-urls, django-url-reverse

I keep getting this error message:

> Reverse for 'tagged' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['\^tag/\(\?P(?P[^/]+)\[\-\\w\]\+\)/\$$']

when trying to load my base.html, because of an anchor tag.
I have looked at other posts with the same issue, but I still don't know where I'm going wrong.

**views.py**

```
class TagIndexView(TagMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'post/index.html'
    model = Post
    paginate_by = '10'
    context_object_name = 'posts'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(tags__slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))

def tagged(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/tagged.html', {'title': 'Tagged'})
```

**urls.py**

```
path(r'^tag/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',TagIndexView.as_view, name='tagged')
```

**base.html**
The anchor tag:

```
<li class="list-group-item"><a href="{% url 'tagged' tag.slug %}">Tags</a></li>
```

But I keep getting a NoReverseMatch. In the anchor tag I have tried "tag.slug", "tag.id", "tag.pk" and some others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `re_path()` instead of `path()` for regular expressions.

   Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions
2. Use `[-\w]*` (0 or more) instead of `[-\w]+` (1 or more) to allow empty string `('',)`.
3. Call `.as_view` with `.as_view()` to create the view function.

```py
#  path(r'^tag/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', TagIndexView.as_view,   name='tagged')
re_path(r'^tag/(?P<slug>[-\w]*)/$', TagIndexView.as_view(), name='tagged')
```